# How to save multiple outputted text files into ONE folder calling multiple sub functions created in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a code in VBA that automates text files and saves them in a folder. I have multiple sub-functions that do the same just with different text files. I would like to create a code where I can call all those subfunctions and save all the output text files into one folder. Below is one of the sub-functions I have created (the other 5 are pretty much the same format):

```
   Sub ic1080_1(Path)

 'Declaring variables
 Dim FName As String, stream As TextStream
 Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

'Create txt file
Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(Path)
........

'Close the text file
stream.Close

 End Sub
```

How can I create a code that will call this sub-function and the other 5 (which have the same format as this one.... test2(), test3(), test4(), test5(), test6() ) and save all the output text files into ONE folder?

Below is the code I am working on with all the sub-functions included:

```
Sub parm_groups()

Dim Path As String

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
NewFolderPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("")

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
If Not fso.FolderExists(NewFolderPath) Then
    fso.CreateFolder NewFolderPath
End If

call ic1080_1.ic1080(NewFolderPath & "ic1080_1.txt")
call test2.test2(NewFolderPath & "test2.txt")
call test3.test3(NewFolderPath & "test3.txt")
call test4.test4(NewFolderPath & "test4.txt")
call test5.test5(NewFolderPath & "test5.txt")

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are already saving text to a file.

If you want to call the subs store the path as an argument and call them like...

```
Sub parm_groups()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject, NewFolderPath As String
    NewFolderPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("")

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If Not fso.FolderExists(NewFolderPath) Then
       fso.CreateFolder NewFolderPath
    End If

    test2.test2("C:\Text2.txt")
    test3.test3("C:\Text3.txt")
    ic1080_1.ic1080_1("C:\ic1080_1.txt")
    test4.test4("C:\text4.txt")
    test5.test5("C:\text5.txt")
End Sub

Sub test2(Path) 'change this line
    ...
  Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(Path)
    ....
End Sub
```

**or**

Create a module, name it `savefile`

```
Sub savefile(Path)
    ...
  Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(Path)
    ....
End Sub
```

and call it like...

```
Sub parm_groups()

    savefile("C:\Text2.txt")
    savefile("C:\Text3.txt")
    savefile("C:\ic1080_1.txt")
    savefile("C:\text4.txt")
    savefile("C:\text5.txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I modify my code to not save the output text in each sub (as I currently have) but instead just use a path as an argument and use it in the sub parm_groups() code to output and save all the files in a specific folder?  I tried to do it as suggested but having the same path name for all sub-functions wouldn't cause an issue when trying to save the text files with that name in that folder? each files has its specific name (ic1080_1, test2, test3, test4, test5) Please see the edited code. Thanks

Comment: I keep getting an error about the format when I try to hardcode it.  Is there a way to save the files into a user-defined folder, instead of hardcoding them directly into the C: drive?

Comment: Yes... That was just my example you can create them in any folder you like. Sometimes the C drive is write protected. try changing the paths from what i have to your folder of choosing.. also what is the format error?

Comment: Gotcha. I changed the folder location (hardcored) and it is saving the files in that location. However, when I run the code, it asks me 5 times to name the folders I am creating and it stores the files out of those folders. I would like to just have the user to input the folder name once where all the text files will be stored. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: Im thinking `NewFolderPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("")` is your issue... try changing that to `NewFolderPath = "C:\locationtofolder"` If all of the subs are the same you can just use one sub and just call it 5 times with a different path name instead of doing 5 seperate subs.

Comment: NewFolderPath = "C:\locationtofolder" will save the text files in an already created folder right? I would like to actually ask the user to create that folder within the code... not save the files into a folder that is already on the C drive.  Also, all the subs are in the same format, the only difference is in the following 2 lines:  stream.Write 1) "EQUIPMENT_ID_DEF,02,0x1" & "," & Chr(34) & "ic1080_1" & Chr(34)   2)  If Left(destgroup, 7) = "ic1080_" And Left(destgroup, 9) <> "ic1080_2_" And ssystem = "A429" And sformat = "BNR" Then. Can I still use only ONE sub?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I tried it but it gives me an error "Run-time error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set" and it directs me to the following line:  Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(Path)

Comment: I added back Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject but now It gives me the error "Run-time error 70, Permission denied"

Comment: at which line? verify you can write to the folder you selected.Also verify the filepaths are correct.

Comment: I was able to fix that issue. We are almost there... Now, the only problem is that the output files are being stored outside the user created folder... see my code edit :)

Comment: what is NewFolderPath showing as? Also minor change... i assumed you wer using `NewFolderPath` inside the sub... if you are not using it, you can remove it from the call function. Just curious on why you are using Application.GetSaveAsFilename("") when that is used to select a file and not a folder?

Comment: I removed the NewFolderPath as suggested since I am not using it in the subs.  I thought Application.GetSaveAsFilename("") was used to create a folder?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to finally save all the txt files to the user created folder :) see final code.  Do you have any suggestions on how to just have one sub instead of 6 and having the following lines as arguments:  stream.Write "EQUIPMENT_ID_DEF,02,0x1" & "," & Chr(34) & "ic1080_1" & Chr(34)                      If Left(destgroup, 7) = "ic1080_" And Left(destgroup, 9) <> "ic1080_2_" And ssystem = "A429" And sformat = "BNR" Then

Comment: Awesome! That would require another post as that is a different issue and requires a different explanation.

Comment: Since the only parts of the code that change is "0x1", "ic1080_1"  and the IF statement in the second line of code (If Left(destgroup, 7) = "ic1080_" And Left(destgroup, 9) <> "ic1080_2_" And ssystem = "A429" And sformat = "BNR" Then)

Comment: Gotcha! I will post another question :)  You are wonderful! Thank you very much for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new sub to call the others.

```
Sub Run_5()
    call ic1080_1(Path)
    call ic1080_2(Path)
    call ic1080_3(Path)
    call ic1080_4(Path)
    call ic1080_5(Path)
End Sub
```

I suggest to modify your procedures to request the Path.
You can do as follows:

```
   Sub ic1080_1(Path as String)
```

Comment: I tried the suggested code but I get the error "ByRer Argument Type Mismatch"  (I included the code above)

Comment: Try to declare the type of variable in your Sub. You are writing only Path. Try using Path as String.